Django admin - using dja have a style problem
i have an issue in the style admin of Django, when i enter on the web admin it show this:

it show a broken style, with black lines
I have this in my user_settings.py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = '/srv/media'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

The version of python is 3.12.3 and Django is 4.2
Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

If that layout is the one visible in your Production environment, I must ask. Have you run the python manage.py collectstatic command in your server? It's required for serving static files correctly in a productive environment. More on this here

You did override Django admin and perhaps inadvertantly caused this. Show us the relevant templates you overrode. Perhaps base_site?
